# Prompt in opening pdf in internet explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, asp.net-3.5

While opening the PDF file in new tab in Internet Explorer, it shows the message "Please Login to View this file."

The same application working fine in Chrome.

Previously the same PDF was visible in iframe, now I'm trying to open the file in new tab. I am expecting to open the PDF same as it opens in other browser.

Comment: Please check the IE browser version, which kind of IE browser version are you using? please check your web site whether you have add the permission management to the PDF file. You could also try to directly open the PDF file in the Internet Explorer, check whether could open the file in IE browser.

Comment: Currently I'm using 11.0.9600.19377 version. Yes, I'm able to open the local files. But the application opening file are not shown.

Comment: In your application, whether you have add the permission management to the PDF file? please check related code and the related file.